# How to stop visual studio from focusing the console upon launching?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Is it possible to stop visual studio and the console window launch by it upon starting debugging to the foreground/stole focus?

I'm using the version `2019 v16.11.5`, and I only could find an option for the breakpoints:

[image]